# Does python's multiprocessing.Manager expose my application to security vulnerabilities?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So I am aware that the multiprocessing.Manager() has the ability to create a socket server for remote connections to the socket over the network.

I simply want to implement multiprocessing.Manager() for a simple shared memory dictionary to retrieve and set flags in the child process that the parent reads.

Does the basic multiprocessing.Manager() automatically bind to an IP address and port or do I have to explicitly tell it to do that? I only want the child and parent processes to have access to the memory from the manager process.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
     m = multiprocessing.Manager()
     d = m.dict()
     d['key_1'] = "Hello"
     p = multiprocessing.Process(target=child_process_init_function, args=(d,))
     p.start()
     p.join()
```